# ssh: X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0 (Linux->Mac)

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, macos

(I was pointed here from stackoverflow, so sorry for cross-posting)

I'm trying to ssh from a Linux machine (Linux Mint 19.2) into my MacBook Pro (OS 10.14.6 or so) in order to start applications such as firefox on the Mac and have the window open on my Linux client (the keyboard of the Mac is broken, and the machine can only be accessed remotely). However, the window does not open, and I get an error `X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0` as soon as I log in, which points to a general ssh problem.
I have tried various things that are suggested in the many postings on this topic, but nothing worked. I have set

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the Mac and restarted the sshd. I have also set `ForwardX11 yes` in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` of the Linux machine. `xauth` is installed on the Mac (in `/opt/local/bin`, which is in my `$PATH`), although an error message during login claims the contrary. Yet the error remains.

Here is a part of what ssh spits out in verbose mode:

```
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/thomas/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 192.168.2.100 ([192.168.2.100]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = de_DE.UTF-8
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward X11.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

As I said, `xauth` is on the Mac:

```
:~> which xauth
/opt/local/bin/xauth
```

so I don't know why it's not found. Any ideas how to fix this? It would be quite important for me to be able to open apps on the Mac.
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

The Mac version of Firefox does not use X11 at all; it uses MacOS's native API (Cocoa) instead. So it cannot be used via X11 forwarding because it is not an X11 application.

In order to fix the error:

```
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward X11.
```

you'll need to add one more line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
XauthLocation /opt/local/bin/xauth
```

and then you may have to restart the `sshd` service:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

After that, you should be able to make SSH connections with X11 forwarding to your Mac, and be able to run any **X11 applications** with their display windows forwarded to the SSH client.

But I'm afraid this will still not allow you to forward **native MacOS applications** the same way. To access them remotely, you would have to enable Mac's *Screen Sharing* service and use a VNC client application to connect to the Mac.

Comment: Can I enable screen sharing on the Mac remotely/from the command line, or is there any other possibility that relies on the command line only? As I said, the keyboard of the Mac is broken, and the machine cannot be accessed anymore directly. As for vnc clients on the Linux side, can you recommend one (directvnc or tiger-vnc, for example)?

Comment: That would be worth posting a whole separate Question for, but [google says you can.](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-screen-sharing-on-macs-via-terminal/) As for Linux VNC client, try whatever is included in your distribution's package manager first: those are likely the most well-integrated to your desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

Following a [comment by Philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625936/ssh-x11-forwarding-request-failed-on-channel-0-linux-mac?noredirect=1#comment117781088_66625936) I added the line `XAuthLocation /opt/local/bin/xauth` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, which solved the general problem of X11 forwarding. However, although "classical" X11 programs now work, other programs such as firefox still do not.